# Python Web scraping - save variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a program in Python to scrape a page every hour and send to me a message on Telegram if something new is added.

I made this code:

```
web_url = 'https://aaaa'
parameters = {'q':'bbbb', 'from':'cccc'}

bot_key = 'dddd'
chat_id = 'eeee'

scraping = requests.get(web_url, params=parameters, timeout = 5)
website_content = BeautifulSoup(scraping.content, 'html.parser')
match = website_content.findAll(name='a', attrs={'class':'ffff'}, href=True)

links = []

for i in match:
    z = i.get('href')
    if z not in links:
        parameters = {'chat_id':chat_id, 'text':z}
        requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_key}/' + 'sendMessage',data=parameters)
        links.append(z)
```

It works, but every time I run the code, the variable links started black. How can I save the variable with new links and reuse it many times?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the variable links started black", but if you mean "the scraped links were erased", then you can use the `pickle` module to save your data to a file, then on re-run you can read the file and decode the data again using the `pickle` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you run a python script, all variables are re-initialized, so you can't use values of the previous run.

What i would do: save the links to a file and read that file every time you run the script.